# why the `user` still have no permission to modify the folder

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

```
user@ubuntu:/var/www$ sudo addgroup webwork
[sudo] password for user: 
user@ubuntu:/var/www$ sudo chmod g+s /var/www
user@ubuntu:/var/www$ sudo chown :webwork /var/www
user@ubuntu:/var/www$ ls -l ../www
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 177 2011-12-13 15:48 index.html

user@ubuntu:/var/www$ sudo usermod -aG webwork user
user@ubuntu:/var/www$ ls -l ../www
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 177 2011-12-13 15:48 index.html

user@ubuntu:/var/www$ ls > t.txt
bash: t.txt: Permission denied

user@ubuntu:/var/www$ uname -n
ubuntu
user@ubuntu:/var/www$ whoami
user
```

I simply want to create a group of webwork and add the current user of `user` to this group so that it can modify the folder of `\var\www`.

**Question**> Why after running the above statement, the `user` still have no permission to modify the folder `/var/www`?

Thank you

// Update -- after logout and login //

```
user@ubuntu:/var/www$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 177 2011-12-13 15:48 index.html
user@ubuntu:/var/www$ ls > t.txt
bash: t.txt: Permission denied
```

Comment: Your `ls` command only shows the permissions of the contents of `/var/www`. Could you run `ls -l /var` and post the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log out and log in again.

Each running process has its own credentials – user, group, secondary group list. When you run `usermod -aG`, you only update the user's information on disk, but you cannot update the group list of currently running shells. You can see it by running `groups` or `id` (shows current credentials) and comparing with `groups user` or `id user` (shows information on disk).

Also, make sure your group actually has write access (`+w`) to the directory. Add it with `sudo chmod g+w /var/www`.

Comment: I have tried and it doesn't work for me.